# Does every set of generators of a finite group contain a minimal set of generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a *finite* group that can be generated from $n$ elements $g_1,...,g_n\in G$.

Now, if $S\subseteq G$ is another set of generators of $G$, can I always find a subset $S'\subseteq S$ of size $\le n$ that still generates $G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

For example, $S_4$ is generated by $(1,2)$ and $(1,2,3,4)$, so it is $2$-generated. However, no subset of size $2$ in $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}$ generates $S_4$.

Comment: In some special cases the answer is yes, for example when $G$ is a finite $p$-group (Burnside's basis theorem).